# What empty ; do in foreach cicle?

Tags: c#

Read some legacy code and read this:

```
  foreach (var val in SomeObj.Values)
        {
            if (!val.IsAlive)
            {
                ;
            }
        }
```

What ";" do?

Comment: It's most likely put there to have a line to set a breakpoint on if `!val.IsAlive`. The `;` statement itself does nothing at all.

Comment: Though, note that Visual Studio allows breakpoints to be set on the curly braces `{` and `}`, so there never really is a point to an isolated `;` like that. Even setting a breakpoint as @Joachim suggests does not explain why the character was placed in the code. You'd have to ask the person who put it there. All we can do is offer opinions, which isn't on-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing. It can be removed with no effect. Perhaps the original developer though he had to "do something" even though he didn't want to do anything.. The code block could have just been left empty